# What to do with a question which is a "duplicate" of 2 different questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, link-only-answers

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22026268/509868) seems to have several possible answers.

One (for now) exists as an answer to this question; OP indicated that the answer is not good enough (might be good for future viewers though, so I upvoted).

I found two other answers, which were posted as answers to different questions. One could use the "close as duplicate" feature, but which question to choose as a target?

Should we encourage OP to post a self-answer with a link to the answer that he chose to fix his problem? (wouldn't that be a "low quality answer"?)

Or is it already as good as it can get (links posted as comments; no accepted answer)?